# How to include multiple config dir in php-fpm?

Tags: configuration, php, wildcards, php7

I'm doing the configuration of **php-fpm**, and I'm experiencing some issues with the `include=` directive in **php-fpm.conf** file.

Here is the default directive :

```
include=/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

But I want to add another path along this path, lets say `/usr/example/php-fpm/*/pool7.0.cfg`.

How can I do that, I tried globing with

```
include=/{/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/*.conf,/usr/example/php-fpm/*/pool7.0.cfg}
```

But it doesn't works..

Thanks for you help !

Comment: I don't know that you can use a wildcard for _directories_ in which to seek files for an `include` directive.  That would be an egregious security flaw (e. g. create new directory, drop new `.conf` file in, force service restart).

Comment: @DopeGhoti It's said that we can use `blob(3)` to make the path, but it doesn't works...

Answer (score 3):

Just use multiple includes as follows:

```
include=/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
include=/usr/example/php-fpm/*/pool7.0.cfg
```

By the way, I know this is a little old question, but I think the answer may be useful for others.